# Parameter substitution in a string bash

Tags: string, bash, parameters, substitution

In my shell script, I had defined few messages that I need to log as INFO, WARN or ERROR.

The messages are as follows:

```
###### This may not be correct syntax as I need to know this #######
BACKUP_INFO="File {} is compressed at path {}."
ERROR_FILE_NOT_EXIST="File {} doesn\'t exist."
OTHER_ERROR="Cannot backup File {}, Reason: {}"
```

I have a methods to log this information in a file:

```
function print_info() {
  echo -e "$(date +'%F %T') ${SCRIPTNAME}: INFO: ${*}" | tee -a ${LOGFILE};
}
```

Now I need to pass my messages to method print info in such a way that the first parameter should be placed at first {}, second parameter should be placed at second {}, and so on.

Even I tried to declare my message as

```
BACKUP_INFO="File $FILE_NAME is compressed at path $BACKUP_DIR."
```

But the problem is the variables FILE_NAME and BACKUP_DIR are inside a method, and the message is defined globally.

Somewhat I want to use it as shown below:

```
print_info $BACKUP_INFO $FILE_NAME $FILE_PATH
```

so that the output should come as

```
2015-03-13 07:05:05 : INFO: File /opt/mgtservices/relay.log is compressed at path /root/backup
```

I need to know the correct syntax how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`printf`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) for that, using "`%s`" for the placeholder.

Here's an example:

```
SCRIPT_NAME="foo.sh"
FORMAT="hello %s, %s"

print_info() {
  format="$1"
  shift
  printf "$(date +%F) $SCRIPT_NAME: $format\n" "$@"
}

name="bob"
message="how are you?"

print_info "$FORMAT" "$name" "$message"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the parameters are context dependent anyway, it doesn't really make much sense to abstract these to the point where you have the message strings in global variables.  Whichever function needs to print `BACKUP_INFO` also needs to know what placeholders there are in the string, so it might as well include the string directly.  If you don't want that, maybe change them into functions, too.

```
print_info () {
    local fmt
    fmt=$1
    shift
    printf "$(date +'%F %T') ${SCRIPTNAME}: INFO: $fmt\n" "$@" | tee -a "$LOGFILE"
}

backup_info () { print_info 'File %s is compressed at path %s.' "$1" "$2"; }
error_file_not_exist () { print_info "File %s doesn't exist." "$1"; }
# XXX FIXME: "other_error" is really a misnomer!
other_error () { print_info 'Cannot backup File %s, Reason: %s' "$1" "$2"; }
```

Somewhat coincidentally, this might actually also offer some benefits if you want to provide localization support for your script; then if the word order of the English strings are wrong for a target language, the translator can override the English formatting function with a different one.